# Javascript - Streaming Audio On The Fly (Web Audio API & XHR)

Tags: javascript, audio, xmlhttprequest, streaming, web-audio-api

I have a simple xmlhttprequest running for fetching an audio file, when it's done fetching it decodes the audio and plays it.

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', /some url/, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function() {
            decode(xhr.response); 
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send(null);
```

The problem with this however, is that the file decodes only after the request is loaded/finished downloading. Is there an approach for streaming audio without having to wait for it to finish downloading?, without the usage of `<audio>` tags

Answer (score 0):

You still need HTML5 `Audio` object but instead of using it directly and playing with it you can use use `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` along with `Audio` element to take advantage of Web API.

***Excerpt from [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001552/ch07.html#s07_1)***

> Rather than going the usual path of loading a sound directly by
>   issuing an XMLHttpRe quest and then decoding the buffer, you can use
>   the media stream audio source node (MediaElementAudioSourceNode) to
>   create nodes that behave much like audio source nodes
>   (AudioSourceNode), but wrap an existing  tag. Once we have this
>   node connected to our audio graph, we can use our knowledge of the Web
>   Audio API to do great things. This small example applies a low-pass
>   filter to the  tag:

***Sample Code:***

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);

function onLoad() {
 var audio = new Audio();
 source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

 var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
 filter.type = filter.LOWPASS;
 filter.frequency.value = 440;

 source.connect(this.filter);
 filter.connect(context.destination);

 audio.src = 'http://example.com/the.mp3';
 audio.play();
}
```